# Merge uneven data frames in R by common column and fill in empty elements by NA

Tags: r, merge

These are examples of two dataframes I am working on. 'Claims' has fewer rows than 'lastaction'.

[image]

My attempts give the following error.

```
newtable <- merge(claims, lastaction, by = "X", all = TRUE)
```

> Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value, value = NA) :    new columns
>   would leave holes after existing columns

```
newtable <- merge(claims, lastaction, by.x = claims$X, by.y = lastaction$X, all = TRUE)
```

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` function works fine for me. As both dataframes have the same column name `X`, it can be used to merge using `by`.

```
claims = data.frame(X = c(10,24,30,35,64,104), 
                    TransactionDateTime = c('JUL-15','APR-17','SEP-15','JUL-15','APR-16','SEP-15'))
claims
#     X TransactionDateTime
# 1  10              JUL-15
# 2  24              APR-17
# 3  30              SEP-15
# 4  35              JUL-15
# 5  64              APR-16
# 6 104              SEP-15

lastaction = data.frame(X = c(10,24,30,35,40,57), lastvalue = c(6,1,4,6,6,1), 
                        Approvalmonth = c('15-OCT','17-JAN','16-MAR','15-OCT','15-SEP','17-JUN'), 
                        lastvalue = c(0,1,0,0,0,1)) 
lastaction
#    X lastvalue Approvalmonth lastvalue
# 1 10         6        15-OCT         0
# 2 24         1        17-JAN         1
# 3 30         4        16-MAR         0
# 4 35         6        15-OCT         0
# 5 40         6        15-SEP         0
# 6 57         1        17-JUN         1

merge(claims, lastaction, by = "X", all = TRUE)
#     X TransactionDateTime lastvalue Approvalmonth lastvalue.1
# 1  10              JUL-15         6        15-OCT           0
# 2  24              APR-17         1        17-JAN           1
# 3  30              SEP-15         4        16-MAR           0
# 4  35              JUL-15         6        15-OCT           0
# 5  40                <NA>         6        15-SEP           0
# 6  57                <NA>         1        17-JUN           1
# 7  64              APR-16        NA          <NA>          NA
# 8 104              SEP-15        NA          <NA>          NA
```

`dplyr`'s `full_join` as well works

```
dplyr::full_join(claims, lastaction, by = 'X')
    X TransactionDateTime lastvalue Approvalmonth lastvalue.y
1  10              JUL-15         6        15-OCT           6
2  24              APR-17         1        17-JAN           1
3  30              SEP-15         4        16-MAR           4
4  35              JUL-15         6        15-OCT           6
5  64              APR-16        NA          <NA>          NA
6 104              SEP-15        NA          <NA>          NA
7  40                <NA>         6        15-SEP           6
8  57                <NA>         1        17-JUN           1
```